# Error updating Visual Studio 2013 for Windows Phone 8.1 SDK Update 3

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to update Visual Studio 2013 for Windows Phone 8 SDK to Windows Phone 8.1 SDK update 3. However, the setup completed with the following errors:

> Hotfix for Microsoft Windows (KB2913642) Server execution failed
>
> Hotfix for Microsoft Windows (KB2910887) Server execution failed
>
> Hotfix for Microsoft Windows (KB2921128) Server execution failed

My computer capacity

- Windows 8.1 Pro, 64-bit
- Ram 4.00 GB(3.87 GB usable)
- Processor: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 1007U @1.150GHz

How can I get rid of this error? Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: have you tried installing seperatly?

Comment: No, what do you mean by installing seperatly? I installed by double click on its installation file VS2013.3.exe along with the packages folder. the installation took long time, and the result was error like above? please help me

Comment: I also installed on another computer, it went smoothly and working as normal without any error.

Comment: @ArunSelvaKumar, I tried to install KB2910887 seperatly, directly from its packages folder\KB2910887\x64\Windows8.1-KB2910887-v2-x64.exe, and it still encountered error "installer encountered an error: 0x8008005 Server Execution Failed". As I found on Microsoft site http://support.microsoft.com/kb/870655 , but I'm not quite sure. Can anyone help?

Comment: hi i tried to follow instruction in support.microsoft.com/kb/870655 and then install those three files manually from package folder, now it works fine.  Thanks everyone